# How to activate datanucleus java-type extensions for JPA?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I have a simple JPA @Entity that has a property of type 
java.util.Locale.

When I try and persist this, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locale: java.util.Locale is not a supported property type. 
       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue( DataTypeUtils.java:174) 
...
```

In the appengine SDK (1.3.1), datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar contains 
plugin.xml which contains the following type conversion "extension":

```
<java-type name="java.util.Locale" persistent="true" embedded="true" 
string-converter="org.datanucleus.store.types.LocaleStringConverter"/>
```

How do I "activate" this type converter in my @Entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a significant limitation of Google's use of datanucleus. See the following (2nd last heading):

http://datanucleus.blogspot.com/2010/01/gaej-and-jdojpa.html